# jQuery hide/show specific div element

Tags: jquery

This is my html code

```
<div class="w-grid-list">
<article class="w-grid-item">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <div class="w-vwrapper">
            <div class="w-post-elm">
                <img width="350" height="233" src="#" sizes="350px">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details" style="display: none;">
                <div class="w-post-elm post_content usg_post_content_1">
                    <p class="prod_text desktop_prod_text" style="display: block;">Солодкі млинці з яблучним варенням.<br>
                        <strong>200 г &nbsp;&nbsp; 714 ккал</strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="product_title">Млинці з сиром та курагою</h2>
            <div class="w-hwrapper">
                <div class="w-post-elm">
                    <span class="w-post-elm-before">Weight: </span>
                    <span class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">200 g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="w-grid-item">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <div class="w-vwrapper">
            <div class="w-post-elm">
                <img width="350" height="233" src="#" sizes="350px">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details" style="display: none;">
                <div class="w-post-elm post_content usg_post_content_1">
                    <p class="prod_text desktop_prod_text" style="display: block;">Солодкі млинці з яблучним варенням.<br>
                        <strong>200 г &nbsp;&nbsp; 714 ккал</strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="product_title">Млинці з сиром та курагою</h2>
            <div class="w-hwrapper">
                <div class="w-post-elm">
                    <span class="w-post-elm-before">Weight: </span>
                    <span class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">200 g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

When user clicked on H2 tag (with 'product_title' class) , then 
hid the DIV element (with class 'product_details') of that Article tag
not other Div element outside this Article .tag

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.product_details').hide();
jQuery('.product_title').click(function(e){  
e.preventDefault();
// hide all span
var $this = jQuery(this).parent().find('div');
jQuery(".product_details").not($this).hide();

// here is what I want to do
$this.toggle();

});
```

But this code is not working properly

Comment: @Taplar updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method for this like:

```
$('.product_title').click(function(){
   $(this).prev('.product_details').hide();
})
```

Using `$(this)` we are only targeting `product_details` div before the currently clicked `product_title` element.

Comment: thank you. this is work for me. but can add show() again clicked on H2 tag?

Comment: You can simply use `toggle()` instead of `hide()`. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The element you want to target is a sibling of the element that triggers the click event, so you can use the .siblings() method to select the previous element, or you can also travel the dom to the parent element (article) then select the element you want to target via .find() method :

```
$(".product-title").on('click', function () {
  $(this).siblings('.product-details').hide('fast');
});
// OR
$(".product-title").on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('article').find('.product-details').hide('fast');
});
```